# Is it possible to assign an address to a macro during a runtime?

Tags: c++

Suppose, there is a macro `MY_MACRO` defined in *header.hpp*. In general, I can overwrite the macro definition from the header file in *source.cpp* with:

```
//source.cpp
#include "header.hpp"

#undef MY_MACRO
#define MY_MACRO 0x080000
```

Now, I have an array (`myData`) in a function, and would like to assign the start address of the array to `MY_MACRO`. I tried to do like below, but it doesn't work:

```
void testFunction()
{
    uint8_t myData[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    #undef MY_MACRO
    #define MY_MACRO &myData
    const uint8_t *dataPointer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(MY_MACRO);
    #undef MY_MACRO
    #define MY_MACRO 0x080000
}
```

What would be the possible way?

Comment: Macros don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Instead of a #define, try a (global) variable.

Comment: I don't think that can work. Macros are handled by the preprocessor, so they're long gone during runtime.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish. (And that cast is very suspicious.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The issue I have is that I need to write a unit test of a function which uses macros from another header file (API from a flash driver). The function try to read a data from a flash address. I was thinking to overwrite the macros, which I'm myself also very skeptical. So, the only way is to write a mock of the API header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to assign an address to a macro during a runtime?

No. Pre-processor macros are processed at pre-processing time, which happens before compilation which happens before runtime.

What you've written does work however. After pre-processing, the resulting c++ will be:

```
uint8_t myData[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
const uint8_t *dataPointer = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&myData);
```

Comment: Thanks eerorika. Yes, I can assign the address of my array. However, in my case I need to write a unit test which try to change the original macro definition from a header file. So, there is only one possibility which is mocking the macro or the header file in my unit test.